# PDFBox using to creating pdf's in HTML form

Tags: pdfbox

i've got another question about the PDFBox. Is it possible to creating new pdf's templates on our webpage and saving it?

Well something like - I want to create PDF document with specific fields as administrator on web page. I have fields which I want to fill by my restrictions and when I saving it i want to "LOCK" fields which i filled.

I hope it's clear.

Comment: No it's not clear :-(

Comment: well, sorry :P Can I create a template (empty doc with only empty fields on my webpage) which administrator can just fill (create fields: name, surname, ID, number etc) and save it as another template? But this one, will be for users of page.

Comment: Well yes, you can create a PDF with fields and then save it. See the CreateSimpleForm.java example. You can set the values later. You can also add fields later. Was that your question? If yes, then this is something you could easily test yourself... your computer won't explode :-)

Comment: meh, maybe another question, which can help me :P When I created rectangle, which I can fill in any case by words: 1. Can I lock the field after first fill? 2. Can I set property for this field, which says about only 1 chance to fill?

Comment: You see, I created doc which can be filled only in few fields (name etc.). But if someone fill this and download / print it - he can still changing this PDF in any case.

Comment: 1) Use `PDField.setReadOnly()`. 2) _property for this field, which says about only 1 chance to fill_ - don't think this exists.